# Is there any way to move RSI Indicator position of Syncfusion Cartesian Chart?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I am trying to RSI Indicator in CandleStick chart using Syncfusion package.
Everything works but if the y axis value is very large say it starts at higher than 10000. But RSI is only shown below 100. So, there is large gap 100-10000 in the chart. How can I remove the gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have analyzed your requirement and the scenario can be achieved by rendering the RSI indicator in the secondary y-axis. Find the code below to accomplish this.

```
SfCartesianChart(
        axes: [
          NumericAxis(
            opposedPosition: true,
            name: 'yAxis',
            
          )
        ],
        indicators: <TechnicalIndicators<_SalesData, DateTime>>[
          RsiIndicator<_SalesData, DateTime>(
              seriesName: 'AAPL',
              yAxisName: 'yAxis',
              //Other configurations
          ),
        ],
        series: <ChartSeries<_SalesData, DateTime>>[
          CandleSeries<_SalesData, DateTime>(
              name: 'AAPL'
              //Other configurations
         )
        ]
       )
```

We have attached main.dart file [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/RSI-1616767402) for your reference.